# Changing a LinearGradientBrush's GradientStops at run time when declared as a static resource and used within a control tempate

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-5.0

I have a resource dictionary which contains the style of a button. Within the control template of the button I have 4 borders, each representing a specific visual state - normal, hover, click, and disabled. 4 story board objects (one for each state) flip the visibility of the corresponding border to visible and the rest of the borders to collapsed. This creates the effect of smooth transition from one state to the next.

Each border, representing a given state, has a 2px border thickness and 10px rounded corners. The border brush is referenced as `BorderBrush="{StaticResource BorderBrushName}"` while the border's background is also declared in a similar way: `Background="{StaticResource BackgroundBrushName}"`.

This works wonderful, however I've been tasked to do some color palette switching. Since we do a lot of explicit styles, and the application is a Silverlight 5 app, I can't really do theming as the application blows up when the explicit style references kick in... That however is a whole another discussion.

So the issue I have is that the only way to "re-theme" the app is to flip the colors in every brush and change the uri of every image, due to the extensive usage of explicit styles.

While being able to do so in other controls, no matter what I try to change the look of the button in question - it has been totally worthless, and I don't know why.

What am i doing wrong? When I isolate the code and drop it in it's own app everything works. Inside the actual app in question... All other elements change their colors/images, accept the button in question.

The code is attached bellow:
`[Theme/Pallete Switching Code]`

```
  public static class ThemeManager
  {
    /// <summary>
    /// Does things.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="newTheme"></param>
    public static void ChangeTheme(PiranhaTheme newTheme)
    {
      Uri defaultUri = new Uri("/MyApp;component/Themes/Blue/Blue.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
      Uri themeUri = null;

      if (newTheme == PiranhaTheme.Blue)
      {
        themeUri = new Uri("/MyApp;component/Themes/Blue/Blue.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
      }
      else if (newTheme == PiranhaTheme.Dark)
      {
        themeUri = new Uri("/MyApp;component/Themes/Dark/Dark.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
      }
      else
      {
        themeUri = new Uri("/MyApp;component/Themes/Light/LightTheme.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
      }

      ResourceDictionary defaultDictionary = ThemeManager.GetResourceDictionary(defaultUri);
      ResourceDictionary themeDictionary = ThemeManager.GetResourceDictionary(themeUri);

      foreach (var key in defaultDictionary.Keys)
      {
        var currentValue = App.Current.Resources[key];
        var newValue = themeDictionary[key];

        if (newValue != null && currentValue != null)
        {
          if(newValue is SolidColorBrush && currentValue is SolidColorBrush)
          {
            var newSolidBrush = (SolidColorBrush)newValue;
            var currentSolidBrush = (SolidColorBrush)currentValue;

            currentSolidBrush.Color = newSolidBrush.Color;
          }
          else if (newValue is LinearGradientBrush && currentValue is LinearGradientBrush)
          {
            var newGradientBrush = (LinearGradientBrush)newValue;
            var currentGradientBrush = (LinearGradientBrush)currentValue;

            currentGradientBrush.GradientStops.Clear();

            for (int i = 0; i < newGradientBrush.GradientStops.Count; i++)
            {
              GradientStop gradientStop = newGradientBrush.GradientStops[i];

              GradientStop newGradientStop = new GradientStop();
              newGradientStop.Color = gradientStop.Color;
              newGradientStop.Offset = gradientStop.Offset;

              currentGradientBrush.GradientStops.Add(newGradientStop);
            }

          }
          else if (newValue is BitmapImage && currentValue is BitmapImage)
          {
            var newBitmapImage = (BitmapImage)newValue;
            var currentBitmapImage = (BitmapImage)currentValue;

            currentBitmapImage.UriSource = newBitmapImage.UriSource;
          }
          else if (newValue is Image && currentValue is Image)
          {
            var newImage = (Image)newValue;
            var curImage = (Image)currentValue;

            curImage.Source = newImage.Source;
          }
        }
      }
    }

    private static ResourceDictionary GetResourceDictionary(Uri dictionaryUri)
    {
      ResourceDictionary result = new ResourceDictionary();

      try
      {
        Application.LoadComponent(result, dictionaryUri);
      }
      catch { }

      return result;
    }
  }
```

`[App.xaml]`

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/MyApp;component/Assets/BlueTheme.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/MyApp;component/Assets/ButtonStyles.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

`[Button Style - On It's Own Resource Dictionary]`

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Style x:Key="MainLaunchMenuButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RegularState" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" >
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HoverState" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" >
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="MousePressedState" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" >
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="DisabledState" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" >
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RegularState" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" >
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HoverState" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" >
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="MousePressedState" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" >
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="DisabledState" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" >
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RegularState" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" >
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HoverState" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" >
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="MousePressedState" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" >
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="DisabledState" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" >
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>   
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RegularState" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" >
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HoverState" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" >
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="MousePressedState" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" >
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="DisabledState" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" >
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Focused"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Border x:Name="RegularState" Visibility="Visible" BorderBrush="{StaticResource MainLaunchMenuButtonRegularStateBorderBrush}" Background="{StaticResource MainLaunchMenuButtonHoverStateBackgroundBrush}" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="10" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                        <Border x:Name="HoverState" Visibility="Collapsed" BorderBrush="{StaticResource MainLaunchMenuButtonHoverStateBorderBrush}" Background="{StaticResource MainLaunchMenuButtonHoverStateBackgroundBrush}" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="10" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                        <Border x:Name="MousePressedState" Visibility="Collapsed" BorderBrush="{StaticResource MainLaunchMenuButtonPressedStateBorderBrush}" Background="{StaticResource MainLaunchMenuButtonPressedStateBackgroundBrush}"  BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="10" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
                        <Border x:Name="DisabledState"  Visibility="Collapsed" BorderBrush="{StaticResource MainLaunchMenuButtonDisabledStateBorderBrush}" Background="{StaticResource MainLaunchMenuButtonDisabledStateBackgroundBrush}" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="10" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

`[Blue Theme]`

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MainWindowBackground" Color="#FF003A6D" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MainLaunchMenuButtonRegularStateBorderBrush" Color="#78A4D4"/>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="MainLaunchMenuButtonRegularStateBackgroundBrush" EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
        <GradientStop Color="#FF002141" Offset="1"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FF1C4973"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FF002141" Offset="0.6"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MainLaunchMenuButtonHoverStateBorderBrush" Color="#FFFF8500"/>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="MainLaunchMenuButtonHoverStateBackgroundBrush" EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
        <GradientStop Color="#FF002141" Offset="1"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FF1C4973"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FF002141" Offset="0.6"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MainLaunchMenuButtonPressedStateBorderBrush" Color="#002141"/>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="MainLaunchMenuButtonPressedStateBackgroundBrush" EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
        <GradientStop Color="#FFFF8500" Offset="0.6"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FFFF8500" Offset="1"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FFFF9B43"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MainLaunchMenuButtonDisabledStateBorderBrush" Color="#8078A4D4"/>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="MainLaunchMenuButtonDisabledStateBackgroundBrush" EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
        <GradientStop Color="#80123C62" Offset="0.6"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#80002141" Offset="1"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#801C4973"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

`[Light Theme]`

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MainWindowBackground" Color="#333333" />
  <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MainLaunchMenuButtonRegularStateBorderBrush" Color="#2F2F2F"/>
  <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="MainLaunchMenuButtonRegularStateBackgroundBrush" EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
    <GradientStop Color="#FF404040"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FF4E4E4E" Offset="0.6"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FF535353" Offset="1"/>
  </LinearGradientBrush>
  <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MainLaunchMenuButtonHoverStateBorderBrush" Color="#28728B"/>
  <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="MainLaunchMenuButtonHoverStateBackgroundBrush" EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
    <GradientStop Color="#FF46C8F6"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FF42C4F2" Offset="0.6"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FF34ADD8" Offset="1"/>
  </LinearGradientBrush>
  <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MainLaunchMenuButtonPressedStateBorderBrush" Color="#2F2F2F"/>
  <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="MainLaunchMenuButtonPressedStateBackgroundBrush" EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
    <GradientStop Color="#FF46C8F6"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FF42C4F2" Offset="0.6"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FF34ADD8" Offset="1"/>
  </LinearGradientBrush>
  <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MainLaunchMenuButtonDisabledStateBorderBrush" Color="#802F2F2F"/>
  <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="MainLaunchMenuButtonDisabledStateBackgroundBrush" EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
    <GradientStop Color="#804D4D4D" Offset="0.6"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#80505050" Offset="1"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#80404040"/>
  </LinearGradientBrush>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I found the solution to this interesting problem. The issue is that while `App.Current.Resources["Key"]` will retrieve a particular resource, that doesn't mean it is the only instance of that resource.

So if one `ResourceDictionary` references another via the `MergedDictionaries` property that effectively creates a new instance of whatever was referenced. So If we have App.xaml, Resource Dictionaries A and B, and styles in A are referencing keys declared in B, than effectively we could have two instances of B - one when we declare a reference in the app.xaml, and the other one in A.

So if we want to change the color of a brush declared in B, than we have to recursively (find every instance of that brush). We would do so by going through every dictionary and it's merged dictionaries collection, and the merged dictionaries of their merged dictionaries.... etc, and change the color code of the brush whenever its key is present (within the current dictionary), and the resource declared under that key is of the same type.